# Clean Data Scraped from teambhp website using rvest in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am doing scraping in R using rvest package. 
i want to scrape user comments and review from teambhp.com car's pages.
Doing this for below link.
[Team BHP REVIEW](http://www.team-bhp.com/forum/official-new-car-reviews/172150-tata-zica-official-review.html)

i am writing following code in r

```
library(rvest)
library(httr)
library(httpuv)

team_bhp <- read_html(httr::GET("http://www.team-bhp.com/forum/official-new-car-reviews/172150-tata-zica-official-review.html"))
all_tables <- team_bhp %>%
    html_nodes(".tcat:nth-child(1) , #posts strong , hr+ div") %>%
    html_text()
```

but i am getting all the text in on list. and that contains spaces and "\t \n" even if i am applying html_text() function to it. how to clean it and convert to data frame. ?

also , i want to do it for all cars reviews available on website. how can i recursively traverse all the car's reviews. ?

Comment: `team_bhp %>%
    html_table(fill=TRUE)%>%
   .[19:35]`?